# BJT Circuit at DC

Tags: transistors, dc, bjt, voltage-divider

I am having trouble understanding how circuit (a) goes to circuit (b). Specifically why (b) does not have 5V at the base with no resistor as equivalent to (a) instead of what it has.

[image]

Comment: The impedance still exists even if you're using the resultant voltage.

Comment: Have you covered Thevenin equivalent yet? In going from (a) to (b), the ONLY thing that was done was convert RB1 and RB2 and VCC of 15V to the Thevenin equivalent circuit.

Comment: Your VBB is **NOT** +5v. Its 1/3 of 5v. Thus, ignoring Ib*Rbb, the Vemitter is 1.66v - 0.6v = 1.06v, and Ie is 1/3mA.

Comment: How do you get 1/3 of 5V for VBB analogsystemsrf?

Comment: I have covered Thevenin equivalent, mkeith, but when I look at this circuit I see that the voltage at the base is the same as the voltage drop across RB2 and did not think it necessary to use Thevenin equivalent. Is that where I am going wrong?

Comment: @Michael, if you are to ignore base current then you would be correct. But in the case of this example, the base current is not being ignored, since there is base current the voltage at the base will not be 5V exactly.

Comment: Ahhh, so simple now, @JCollins. Thank you. I feel like an idiot.

Comment: No problems @Michael. Don't worry it's an easy mistake to make when you're used to making 'engineering approximations'. I graduated from university 7 years ago now, so I'm a little concerned that I recognised what text that question came from...

Comment: It is the book you mention below. However, it's the 7th ed, Ex. 6.10. Should I not be using the figures from my textbooks on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition from figure (a) to figure (b) is the bias network has been changed to the Thevenin equivalent.

This image looks like it is straight out of Microelectronic Circuits by Sedra & Smith. It's example 5.10 (figure 5.40) in my 5th edition. Which also clearly states that the first step that is completed is the simplification of the bias network by using Thevenin's theorem.